# My string disappear

Tags: c#, string, textbox

I have got a text in the textbox. For example: `Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.`

I can put all the text in a string; I use this.:

```
sline = textBox1.Text;
string[] s = sline.Split(' ');
```

However, sometimes I need some words all together. For example:

```
Also, edit your ** previous questions to improve *** formatting and clarity.
```

I need the words between `**` and `***`.

I used this method.:

```
string startWord = "**";
string endWord = "***";
int startIndex = sline.IndexOf(startWord) + startWord.Length;
sline = sline.Substring(startIndex);
int cutLength = sline.IndexOf(endWord);
string result = sline.Substring(0, cutLength + 1);
```

And afterwords, I would like use the different two strings.

This works so far.

My problem:

In the end I would like give back to the textbox the `result` string, bringing back the complete words [previous questions to improve], and after I got back the other words, add `questions to improve`

Then my textbox would look like this: `previous questions to improve questions to improve`

I tried the put one checking in the program

```
if (s[i].ToString().Contains(result.ToString()))
{
          continue;
}
```

But in this situation, the result brings back good, but all the others disappear from `s[i]`.

My goal: give back *all* the text.

Comment: what is your exact output???

Comment: You have to give more details(code). The way it is makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, you need to duplicate the text between ** & ****

```
        string strVal = "Hello **World*** one more time world" ;//your original text
        string result = "World"; // the result u want to replace/duplicate which you got from your above operations

        string strFinalResult = strVal.Replace("**" + result + "***", result +" " +  result);//your final result
        //Your final Result :  Hello World World one more time world
```